# Is it possible to use affdex-sdk in node.js and save emotion data to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, affdex-sdk

I find the examples for affdex javascript sdk use the sdk in the frontend webpage.
Is it possible to use the sdk in Node.js?  I'd like to save the emotion data to MongoDB. 
Or can I pass the emotion data I get in the fronend to Node.js in the backend? Then save the data from Node.js to MongoDB?
According to the documentation, the **CameraDetector** constructor expects four parameters { divRoot, width, height, faceMode }.  Which means I need to include a **div** element. But Node.js cannot manipulate frontend elements natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current published version of the SDK cannot be used from NodeJS .. Not because it needs a DOM, but because internally it uses [MEMFS](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html#file-system-overview) to load the expressions models.